# swift can't decode string with escape sequence

Tags: json, swift, decode

I have string on format `SO\/ME\/STR\/ING`. And I want to have mock json for testing. And when I create json with format like:

```
let json = """
{ "str": "SO\/ME\/STR\/ING" } // Error: Invalid escape sequence in literal
"""
```

For what I wrote it like `SO\\/ME\\/STR\\/ING`. But it decodes incorrect:

```
let json = """
{
    "str": "SO\\/ME\\/STR\\/ING",
}
"""
let jsonData = Data(json.utf8)

let decoder = JSONDecoder()

do {
    let model = try decoder.decode(Model.self, from: jsonData)
    print(model) // Model(str: "SO/ME/STR/ING")
} catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

How to correctly decode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need 4 backslashes in the swift string to represent an actual backslash in `model.str`:

```
let json = """
{
    "str": "\\\\",
}
"""
let jsonData = Data(json.utf8)

let decoder = JSONDecoder()

do {
    let model = try decoder.decode(Model.self, from: jsonData)
    print(model.str) // prints a single backslash
} catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

A backslash in a *JSON* string needs to be escaped, so you need 2 backslashes in the JSON string, but to write this in a *Swift* string literal, you need to escape those two backslashes too. Hence the 4 backslashes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a raw string literal (`#"..."#`) aka [Extended String Delimiters](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/StringsAndCharacters.html) to represent this escaped string as like "what I see is what I get":

```
let string = #"""
"SO\/ME\/STR\/ING"
"""#
```

Caution: your JSON String should be a valid JSON and has to be properly escaped if needed as well:
The two character sequence "`\/`" escapes a "solidus" (in JSON terminology). The string above will be printed as "`SO/ME/STR/ING`".

If you would like it to be printed as `SO\/ME\/STR\/ING`, your JSON string literal can be defined as

```
let json = #"""
{
    "str": "SO\\/ME\\/STR\\/ING"
}
"""#
```

The above string literal is a *valid* JSON String respectively a valid JSON Object and can be used as is. However, this doesn't mean it is what you expect ;)

You have to convert the string literal into a Data value using Unicode (UTF-8) before you can use to in a JSON decoder.

see also: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/162/how-to-use-raw-strings-in-swift