# Unable to decode json string value enclosed within curly brackets, escaping character and double quotes using Swift Decodable

Tags: json, swift, parsing, decodable

Here is a piece of the json code that I'm trying to decode using Swift Decodable :

```
var json = """
        {
           "orders":[
              {
                "extra":"{\"desired_pick_up_time\":\"ASAP\"}"
              }
           ]
        }
"""
```

As you can see, the value of the extra key enclosed within :

- curly brackets
- escaping character
- double quotes.

Which make pretty tricky the decoding.

This is the model I wrote in order to decode this :

```
struct Welcome: Decodable {
    let orders: [Order]
}

// MARK: - Order
struct Order: Decodable {
    let extra: String
}
```

Which return a nil value when I try to decode it:

```
let jsonData = json.data(using: .utf8)!

let decoder = JSONDecoder()

do {
    let welcome = try? decoder.decode(Welcome.self, from: jsonData)
    print(welcome)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66254719/swift-cant-decode-string-with-escape-sequence/66254877#66254877

Comment: Basically, the backslashes in your JSON needs to be escaped, otherwise they will escape the quote instead (the quotes don't need to be escaped in a multiline string, but it doesn't matter if you do). I'm not sure if this is too similar to the possible duplicate...

Answer (score 0):

First of all – as mentioned in the comments – the backslashes in the JSON must be escaped using the multiline string literal syntax

```
let json = """
{
    "orders":[{"extra":"{\\"desired_pick_up_time\\":\\"ASAP\\"}"}]
}
"""
```

Second of all the value for key `extra` is another JSON string which needs to be decoded on a second level. This requires the implementation of `init(from decoder`

```
struct Welcome: Decodable {
    let orders: [Order]
}

// MARK: - Order
struct Order: Decodable {
    let extra: Extra
    
    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey { case extra }
    
    init(from decoder : Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let extraString = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .extra)
        let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
        jsonDecoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
        extra = try jsonDecoder.decode(Extra.self, from: Data(extraString.utf8))
    }
}

struct Extra : Decodable {
    let desiredPickUpTime : String
}


let data = Data(json.utf8)

do {
    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Welcome.self, from: data)
    print(result)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```