# Swift JSON string data decoding with escaping character

Tags: ios, swift, decodable

I am getting an error when I am going to decode data response which contains escaping character string .

To demonstrate, I created a playground.

```
import Foundation

struct Example: Decodable {
    let jsonString: String
}

let jsonStr = """
{
    "jsonString": "\\C This is a string with a backslash and no escaping."
}
"""

let jsonData = jsonStr.data(using: .utf8)!

do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
    let example = try decoder.decode(Example.self, from: jsonData)
    
    print(example.jsonString)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Then I get an error :

`dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "The given data was not valid JSON.", underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid escape sequence 'C' around line 2, column 21." UserInfo={NSJSONSerializationErrorIndex=22, NSDebugDescription=Invalid escape sequence 'C' around line 2, column 21.})))`

So my question is how to decode such a data in Swift ?

Comment: As the error says - this is not valid JSON. Valid JSON strings should not contain `\C`. Did you perhaps mean `\\C` (representing *one* backslash followed by "C")? That would be written as `\\\\C` in a Swift string literal.

Comment: In any case, if whatever is outputting this JSON is written correctly, you do not need to of anything special in Swift.

Comment: Actually I am getting data from the backend similar to this ? I used few online json validator and verified that this is a valid  json. And I found that containing `\\C` is normal in Json. So I wonder how people deal with such string with swift ?

Comment: Yes, `\\C` is normal in JSON. `\C` (which is what your Swift string literal represents) is not. Did you actually try decoding something from an actual backend, instead of handwriting your own JSON as Swift string literals?

Comment: mm yes, then how can I decode such string with escaping character in to swift type ? I this this should be a common problem to anyone since `\\C`  is normal in JSON.

Comment: @Sweeper Imagine I am getting a response from a external backend which is not belongs to me, then how can I apply [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66254719/swift-cant-decode-string-with-escape-sequence) answer to this scenario ?

Comment: If you *actually* got `\C` and not `\\C`, then it's not valid JSON. Fix the backend or write your own parser.

Comment: Opz there is a misunderstanding here. I am getting `\\C` which is a valid JSON ? If you could please run the posted code in xcode playground. this is a huge help for me. @Sweeper

Comment: The code you posted does not represent `\\C`. It represents `\C`. Please read the duplicate target carefully.

Comment: I meant ""jsonString": "\\C This is a string with a backslash and no escaping." this contains a `\\C`. If I remove `\\C`   , then my code will give me a success on decoding. so the issue is with `\\C`. ! @Sweeper